# I get a Content-Type error while sending a request

Tags: python, python-requests, twitch

I want to follow another channel with my own channel with the Twitch API. I prepared the code in python according to the codes from the Develepor page. But when I make a request I get an error like **"Request body was not parsable. Attempted Content-Type: " application / json \ "**. My code is below. How can I do it? Can you help me?

```
import requests

headers = {
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'Client-Id': 'clientid',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
}
data = {
    "to_id": "610766140", "from_id": "664978624"
}
response = requests.post("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows", headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't close ` 'Authorization': 'Bearer token,` with a single quote.

Comment: I actually turned it off. It was deleted while typing here. It gives an error as I stated and although I researched, I could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You told it you were going to send JSON, then you didn't send JSON.

```
import requests

headers = {
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'Client-Id': 'clientid',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
}
data = {
    "to_id": "610766140", "from_id": "664978624"
}
response = requests.post("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows", headers=headers, json=data)
print(response.text)
```